# Menu fixed li width 100%

Tags: html, css

I have a menu fixed on top of my page.
My problem is the `li`. It is not getting 100% width. There is a margin left on the first `li` (LOGO) and the second `li` (login) text is somewhere else, but not in my page.

What is wrong with my menu?

https://jsfiddle.net/c96742fu/

CSS

```
#menu {
 display:table;
 background-color: #000;
 position:fixed;
 width:100%;
 top:0;
 margin:0;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 height:45px;
 z-index:100;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #999;
}
#menu a:link, #menu a:visited, #menu a:hover{
 color: #fff;
}
#menu ul{
 width:100%;
 list-style-type: none;
}
#menu li{
 text-align:left;
 display: table-cell;
 width:50%;
 border:1px solid yellow;
}
.right{
 text-align:right !important;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul id=menu>
<li><a href=/index.php>LOGO</a></li>
<li class=right>login</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a default padding for the `<ul>`. Try this to fix it:

```css
#menu {padding: 0;}
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c96742fu/1/**

For better results, try adding a universal reset as said by everyone:

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the "universal reset" which would include the body padding as well but this works. :)

Comment: body {margin: 0;padding: 0;} I have this on body, what is wrong?

Comment: @renatacosta That applies only for the body not for the children.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

to reset default css.

https://jsfiddle.net/c96742fu/